# Is a way to return Future[Unit]?

Tags: scala

I have a method returning Unit originally. After changing returned type to Future[Unit], I can't find out a way to change the method body. The least line is a method call.

Comment: Try `Future { () }`

Comment: or even `Future.successful(())`

Comment: The second approach passes the compiler, but not the first one. Thanks.

Comment: The first approach also passes the compiler in my second try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return a `Future` that holds a value of `Unit`

```
def doSomething():Future[Unit] = {
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3)
  println("hi")
  Future.successful(())
}
```

Comment: The `Unit` companion object is not the same as `()`, and doesn't have type `Unit`—your first example only works because of Scala's value discarding.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi Sorry, I wasn't clear, but your edit is the wrong way around. :) The OP wants a `Future[Unit]`, so they need to use `()` (which is the only value of type `Unit`).

Comment: @TravisBrown isn't () the same is Unit?

Comment: No, it's a value of type `Unit`. `Unit` the value is a value of type `Unit.type`, which is different.

Comment: _Technically_ `Future.successful(Unit)` will still work if the val or method is annotated with `Future[Unit]` from value discarding. But it covers up what is really going on.

Answer (score 25):

In Scala 2.12 the [built-in](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future$.html#unit:scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]) `Future.unit` is the way to go. It has the benefit of being cached.